# Apply only certain events in a div for Swipe Navigation?

Tags: angular, hammer.js, pointer-events

I'm trying to implement swipe navigation for my mobile website. I'm using Angular 2 with hammerjs for the swipe event. I'm trying to figure out a good solution as to how I can add the swipe event.

I have thought of using the **body** although realized that I have to disable a lot of pointer events with divs sitting on top of the body stack.

So instead, I had placed a positioned fullscreen div in front of everything, and wish to catch the swipe event there. This however blocks all click events below the div with

```
pointer-events: none
```

removing all events (including swipe).

Is there a way I can only have this div detect my swipe events only or is there a better way to implement this?